# Open a file on remote server [path issue]

Tags: java, command-line, ms-word

I'm developing a vehicle storage application.  One feature is being able to store documents in different formats (word, excel, pdf) on a remote server WITHOUT having to map the server as separate drive.
Everything works fine if the file to be opened is on the local hard drive (ie, "C:/Documents/FileToOpen.docx"), but I can't figure out the path structure for a path (ie, "C:/Documents/FileToOpen.docx" on server "SERVER06").  I've tried "//SERVER06/C/Documents/FileToOpen.docx" and permutations thereof, but no joy so far.

```
public class Attachments extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    String docPath = "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Office/Office14/WINWORD.EXE";
    String excelPath = "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Office/Office14/EXCEL.EXE";
    String pdfPath = "C:/Program Files/Adobe/Reader 11.0/Reader/AcroRd32.exe";

    /**
     * Creates new form Attachments
     */
    public Attachments() {
        initComponents();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setResizable(false);

    }

    public void setList(Set attachmentList) {
        DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
        Iterator i = attachmentList.iterator();
        int counter = 0;
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            model.add(counter, (Attachment) i.next());
            counter++;
        }
        listAttachments.setModel(model);
    }

    //form generation

    private void btnViewActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        Attachment a = (Attachment) listAttachments.getSelectedValue();
        String type = a.getAttachmentUrl().substring(a.getAttachmentUrl().indexOf("."));
        String prog = "";
        if (type.substring(0, 2).equals(".d")) {
            prog = docPath;
        } else if (type.substring(0, 2).equals(".p")) {
            prog = pdfPath;
        } else if (type.substring(0, 2).equals(".x")) {
            prog = excelPath;
        }

        String commandString = "\"" + prog + "\" \"" + a.getAttachmentUrl() + "\"";
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        try {
            rt.exec(commandString);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void jButtonCloseActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        this.setVisible(false);
        this.dispose();
    }
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your server is using Windows operating system, the server firstly need to share the folder that contains the documents. To do this, go to the server, select the folder, right click and choose 'share'. To verify, go back to the client machine, open windows explorer and type \SERVER06
If your folder sharing is successful, you should see a folder called 'Documents'. If all these are fine this far, your application just need to open the file using "\\SERVER06\Documents\FileToOpen.docx".

Comment: Ok....it must be Friday, I forgot about "/" vs "\" when using java.  The database was storing "//SERVER06/Documents/FileToOpen.docx".  Changed it to "\\\\SERVER06\\Documents\\FileToOpen.docx" and it worked fine.  Much thanks!